# Creating a pure javascript range slider control

Tags: javascript

I managed to create  a somewhat working slider control but something feels kind of off. It doesnt quite behave as a normal control should. Sometimes while sliding it gets stuck and well, you might want to see for yourself.

How would you create the slider so that it slides smoothly without interruption or the user needing the cursor exactly on the red track?

```
function createRange(e) {
    var range = (((e.offsetX - 0) * (255 - 0)) / (200-40 - 0)) + 0;
  var rounded = Math.round(range);

  return rounded;
}

function colorSlider(e) {
    createRange(e)
}

var dragging = false;

document.getElementById("knob").addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
    dragging = true;
  e.target.style.pointerEvents = "none"
})

window.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  if (dragging) {
    if (createRange(e) <= 255) {
      document.getElementById("knob").style.left =  e.offsetX + "px"
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: wouldn't you need a mouseup event listener that sets dragging to false when the mouse is released?

Comment: Why not use `<input type="range">`?

Comment: @torazaburo too easy and too much css and prefixes to customize the design

Comment: That's the first time I can recall some solution being criticized for being "too easy". Anyway, to style your slider, you're also going to need CSS.

Comment: @torazaburo ya, right now its really ugly for testing purposes hehe. I have used the html5 slider before. It can be also styled, every part of it but the amount of css required is crazy. Also with javascript you can apply cool complex easing effects and customize the entire thing like crazy

Comment: Understood. Of course, the built-in slider won't have the "sticking" problem you're wrestling with. :-)

Comment: @torazaburo ok, I think you understood that its kind of like sport :D. For example, while css has in built transforms, it was was fun working with 3d matrix multiplication. Just because the problem was so fun haha

Comment: @Asperger - By the way, old post but it is appreciated, along with some of the corrections. Offered. II also concur with all you've said about making your own vs. customizing a stock "range" control. Even with all the convenient sites that let you dial in all your preferred styles, the end product usually is NOT responsive, and still seldom yields the same  appearance on all browsers and devices (IE, of course, is STILL a pain, even at v. 11!). I've approached mine a little differently than yours, but in the end was much more satisfied with my own, and the total CSS styling was less too!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a fixed version of your slider.

```js
var dragging = false;
var knobOffset = 0;

var track = document.getElementById('track'),
    knob = document.getElementById('knob'),

    trackWidth = track.offsetWidth,
    trackLeft = track.offsetLeft,
    trackRight = trackLeft + trackWidth,

    knobWidth = knob.offsetWidth,
    maxRight = trackWidth - knobWidth; // relatively to track

knob.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
    // knob offset relatively to track
    knobOffset = e.clientX - knob.offsetLeft;
    dragging = true;
});

window.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e) {
    dragging = false;
})

window.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  if (dragging) {
      // current knob offset, relative to track
      var offset = e.clientX - trackLeft - knobOffset;
      if(offset < 0) {
        var offset = 0;
      } else if(offset > maxRight) {
        var offset = maxRight;
      }
        
      knob.style.left = offset + "px"
  }
});
```

```css
#track {width: 200px;height: 5px; margin:100px; background: red}
#knob {height: 10px; width: 40px; background: black;position: relative; }
```

```html
<div id='track'>
  <div id="knob"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh crap, the problem with the offset, the idea behind solving it was so obvious and I didnt see it. Crap. Thanks for putting me on the right track. Accepted the answer!